# Proof verification countability of rationals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Exercise 1 in section 7 of chapter 1 in Munkres Topology book asks to show that the rationals are countably infinite. We have already shown that the set of positive rationals $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ is countably infinite. I did the following:

Let $h:\mathbb{Z}^{+}\to \mathbb{Q}^{+}$ be a bijection. Define $f:\mathbb{Z}^{+}\to \mathbb{Q}$ by $f(1)=0$ and, for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$,

$$f(2k)=h(k)$$
$$f(2k+1)=-h(k)$$

The surjectivity of $f$ follows from the surjectivity of $h$. Hence $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable by Theorem $7.1$ in the book. $\mathbb{Q}$ is countably infinite because it contains $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ as a subset. Alternatively we can also check that $f$ is injective.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.